# text /content search in Share point 2010 documents

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have to make my search text enabled with inside of documents, I mean search "abc" which is written in a "XYZ.docx" of document library.
Please let me know How can we achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think search already does this for Word documents, for other file types, you'll need what's called "iFilters" which are plugins that tell the search engine how to index the contents of a file.

Comment: James is correct, by default SharePoint will search inside all Office documents.
For PDF files however you will need to install the appropriate IFilter